# Reading sparse matrix from binary file

Tags: python, performance, matrix, serialization, scipy

I have binary files containing sparse matrices. Their format is:

```
number of rows int
    length of a row int
        column index int
        value float
```

Reading each row with a single struct call instead of looping through each row with single struct calls gave me roughly a 2-fold speedup. I'm parsing 1 GB sized matrices and I would like to speed this proces up even further.

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import struct
def read_sparse_matrix(handle):
    cols = []
    rows = []
    weights = []
    numrows = struct.unpack('i' , handle.read(4))[0]
    shape = numrows
    for rownum in range(numrows):
        rowlen = struct.unpack('i', handle.read(4))[0]
        row = list(struct.unpack("if" * rowlen, handle.read(8 * rowlen)))
        cols += row[::2]
        weights += row[1::2]
        rows += [rownum] * rowlen
    return coo_matrix((weights, (rows, cols)), shape=(shape, shape))
```

A file contains multiple of these matrices, and other informatinon, so the size of the file is not informative about the structure of the matrix.

Comment: Can you change the format? If so (and you don't need it to be human readable), you should probably just serialize the data. That should be faster.

Comment: Have you tried reading (or `mmap`ping) the entire file into a buffer, and using `struct.unpack_from` to decode the data?

Comment: Can you link a sample file?

Answer (score 1):

This question is about elapsed run times.
Please include
[cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
observations as part of the question.

---

The irregular on-disk structure of the data isn't
doing you any favors, as it complicates any approach
that wants to process bigger chunks at a time.
Barring cython or numba JIT, the current code
looks like it's about as fast as it's going to get.

The slicing with a stride of 2,
for `cols` and `weights` is very nice.

---

Once we've written a giant file,
it's unclear how many times it will be read.
You might care to reformat the data
to support multiple re-reads.

Consider changing the on-disk format using
[savez_compressed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)
so that at read time you can take advantage of a rapid
[load](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).
(The [parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)
compressed format is also fairly attractive.)